# Gzip apache camel request for rest

Tags: java, json, apache, rest, apache-camel

I am using apache camel for rest service calls from spring

Now we need to send the json request in our body to be passed in GZIP using apache camel. I tried by adding CONTENT_ENCODING as gzip, but it does not work. Please see the code

> public void process(Exchange exchange) {
>             exchange.setPattern(ExchangePattern.InOut);
>             exchange.setProperty(Exchange.CHARSET_NAME, "UTF-8");           Message
>   inMessage = exchange.getIn();             inMessage.setHeader(ACCEPT_HEADER,
>   "application/json");          inMessage.setHeader(CONTENT_TYPE,
>   "application/json");
>             inMessage.setHeader(Constants.ACCEPT_ENCODING,
>   Constants.ACCEPT_ENCODING_TYPE);
>                 inMessage.setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_ENCODING, "gzip");  inMessage.setBody(body);

In the camelContext.xml,

we have defined

```
 <route streamCache="true">
            <from uri="direct:setUpload" />
            <recipientList>
                <simple>cxfrs://{{uploadSample.url}}?throwExceptionOnFailure=false</simple>
            </recipientList>
            <unmarshal ref="sampleParser" />
        </route>
```

Do we need to set any other things to gzip the body JSON request

Please help how to correct this

Regards
Hari

Comment: add a gzip endpoint before recipientList and give a try.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion, I tried it , but does not solve the issue, The json request does not get gzipped after giving end point

Comment: You can set the [@org.apache.cxf.annotations.GZIP][1] annotation in the service class method.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10784422/accepting-gzipped-requests-in-cxf

Comment: thank you for your suggestion, I am getting the error , java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to org.apache.cxf.message.MessageContentsList. Do you know whether there is any issue with the type converter if the type becomes byte array

Answer (score 0):

You can try to convert json string to gzip before recipient list.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
GZIPOutputStream gzip = new GZIPOutputStream(out);
gzip.write(str.getBytes());
exchange.setBody(out.toString());
```